# ¿Cómo pasar información en un input al seleccionar una opción?

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

tengo un formulario donde agrego "Oficinas", dentro de el tengo que escoger de un select el nombre de un "empleado"(es una tabla). Mi duda es como podría hacer que al seleccionar a una persona me aparezca en un input su dirección traída desde su respectiva tabla.

EN ESTA FUNCION LE PASO LOS EMPLEADOS AL FORMULARIO OFICINAS

```
public function create()
{
    $empleado = Empleado::all();
    return view('admin.crearOficina', compact('empleado'));
}
```

ESTE ES MI FORMULARIO, QUIERO QUE EN EL INPUT DIRECCION PERSONAL SE PASE EL DATO DE ACUERDO AL USUARIO SELECCIONADO

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="nombre_oficina" class="font-weight-normal">
     NOMBRE DE LA OFICINA
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="nombre_oficina" name="nombre_oficina">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="ubicacion_oficina" class="font-weight-normal">
     UBICACIÓN
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="ubicacion_oficina" 
     name="ubicacion_oficina">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <label for="id_empleado" class="font-weight-normal">
     EMPLEADO
    </label>
    <select type="text" class="form-control" id="id_empleado" 
    name="id_empleado">
     <option disabled selected>-- ELIGE --</option>
     @foreach ($empleado as $empleado)
     <option {{old('id_empleado') == $empleado->id_empleado? 
  'selected' : ''}} value="{{ $empleado->id_empleado}}"}}>
     {{$id_empleado->nombre}}
     </option>
        @endforeach
    </select> 
    <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
        <label for="direccion_empleado" class="font-weight- 
     normal">DIRECCION PERSONAL</label>
        <input type="text" id="direccion_empleado" 
     name="direccion_empleado">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muéstranos que tienes de código así es difícil ayudarte con lo que tienes solo te puedo decir que tienes que tener el modelo para realizar la consulta  y sobre el plantear condiciones para que haga la respectiva validación de los datos y después los escriba en tu HTML y si no responde tu pregunta  se mas claro  !!!!!!!que tienes echo!!!!!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Sin poner el código es difícil poder ayudarte. No obstante te pongo un ejemplo de lo que creo que he entendido que necesitas.

Lo que entiendo yo que necesitas es que al cambiar de empleado del desplegable del select, se ponga automáticamente en un input "oficina" la oficina a la que pertenece el usuario.

Ésto puedes hacerlo con el atributo "onChange". Este atributo se coloca en la etiqueta de select de la siguiente forma: onchange="funcionQueQuieresUsar()" y cada vez que se cambie el valor del desplegable se ejecutará dicha función.

Por otro lado creas la función necesaria que ejecute el código que necesitas. En el ejemplo que te mando, lo que hace la función está comentado línea a línea para que sea lo más entendible posible.

Mas o menos sería algo así:

```js
function seleccionarOficina(){
  //Creamos una variable user en la cual se almacena el valor que tenga en ese momento el select con el id "usuario"
  let user = document.querySelector("#usuario").value;
  
  //Buscamos el input que tiene el id "oficina" y le añadimos la cadena de texto "Oficina de" mas el valor de la variable que hemos creado en el paso anterior
  document.querySelector("#oficina").value = "Oficina de "+user;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <select name="usuario" id="usuario" onChange="seleccionarOficina()">
    <option value="---">---</option>
    <option value="pedro">Pedro</option>
    <option value="juan">Juan</option>
    <option value="andres">Andres</option>
  </select>
  
  <input type="text" value="---" id="oficina">
</form>
```

Te dejo tambien el enlace a codepen donde puedes ver también el código -> https://codepen.io/dryant/pen/GRMrzRo?editors=1010

Espero haber solucionado tu duda. Un saludo! :)